# How do I convert a Zip into an array in rust 0.8?

Tags: arrays, iterator, zip, rust, rust-0.8

The [docs](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.8/std/iter/index.html) seem to indicate that after zipping two iterators together, you can turn them into an array with `.from_iterator()`, but when I try to do this, rust reports:

```
std::iter::Zip<std::vec::VecIterator<,int>,std::vec::VecIterator<,int>>` does not implement any method in scope named `from_iterator`
```

Could someone please give working sample code for rust 0.8 that turns a Zip into an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be `FromIterator::from_iterator(iterator)`.

The more commonly used interface for that is [`Iterator.collect`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#fn.collect) (link is to master docs, but it's the same in [0.8](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.8/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#fn.collect) and [0.9](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/0.9/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#fn.collect)), whereby you will call `iterator.collect()`.

Answer (score 1):

Rust 0.8 is dated, you should upgrade to 0.9. The following works in 0.9:

```
let a = ~[1,12,3,67];
let b = ~[56,74,13,2];
let c: ~[(&int,&int)] = a.iter().zip(b.iter()).collect();
println!("{:?}", c);
```

Result:

```
~[(&1, &56), (&12, &74), (&3, &13), (&67, &2)]
```

Comment: I would, but Homebrew doesn't have a formula for installing 0.9 yet.

Comment: @mcandre: I believe you can specify `--HEAD` and it'll install master—that's where the action is and I would strongly recommend that you use that rather than 0.8 or 0.9.